#  how to slide down 1 picture every specific time and so on

Tags: javascript, slideshow

i want to make slideshow and I want to be its behavior every 2 minutes slide down 1 pictures and so on , until the end of the images , and start again from the first picture .

I tried to make it and i make part of it (every 2 minutes change picture) but not slide down 1 pictures but change picture without slide down .

And one help me to make entire slideshow

My code is below

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="images/slideshow.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <img src="images/slideshow2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <img src="images/slideshow3.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <img src="images/slideshow4.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <img src="images/slideshow5.jpg" alt="" title="" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = slideShow;
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
var counter = 0;
function slideShow(){
    var fatherElem = document.getElementById('slideshow');
    var fatherChildren = fatherElem.children;
    var fatherElemScroll = fatherElem.scrollTop;
    counter++;
    if (fatherChildren.length > counter) {
        fatherElem.scrollTop += 300;
    }
    else {
        fatherElem.scrollTop = 0;
        counter = 0;
    }

    setTimeout(slideShow, 1000);
    document.getElementsByName('SearchBox')[0].value = counter;
}
```

I'm sorry for my big question but i'm really need help

Answer (score 0):

You're manipulating scrollTop on the slideshow div by 300px every second.  If your images are exactly 300px high and your div is exactly 300px high with no overflow and your div forces your images to be vertically in a row, then what your code would do is switch to the next image every second.  So, in answer to your questions:

1. You have not written any code for the image to slide.  Changing scrollTop by 300 is a sudden change, not a sliding change.
2. Your code changes the scrollTop value every second, not every two minutes.  The second parameter to setTimeout is a value in milliseconds.  If you want two minutes, you would have to set that value to (1000 * 60 * 2).

Here's your code in action on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NyYpB/ with some real images.

If you want the images to actually slide, then you will have to write some animation code to slowly manipulate scrollTop from it's present value to the enxt higher value continuously over the period of time you want the animation to run.

Animation can be tricky to do well from scratch.  Most people will choose to either use CSS3 animation or use an animation library (like the one in jQuery or YUI) that has already done the right kind of tweening work for you because it will be faster and probably generate a higher quality result.

Here's a working example you can see and play with using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CyCDD/.

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="http://friend.smugmug.com/Sports/Palo-Alto-Rowing-Club-2011/Pacific-Regatta-Men/Rowing-201102130938160417/1190079664_chLyW-Ti.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <img src="http://friend.smugmug.com/Sports/Palo-Alto-Rowing-Club-2011/Pacific-Regatta-Men/Rowing-201102130941050422/1190083195_Az688-Ti.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <img src="http://friend.smugmug.com/Sports/Palo-Alto-Rowing-Club-2011/Pacific-Regatta-Men/Rowing-201102130941050421/1190083481_C3nag-Ti.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <img src="http://friend.smugmug.com/Sports/Palo-Alto-Rowing-Club-2011/Pacific-Regatta-Men/Rowing-201102130941070426/1190078330_umaLY-Ti.jpg" alt="" title="" />
    <img src="http://friend.smugmug.com/Sports/Palo-Alto-Rowing-Club-2011/Pacific-Regatta-Men/Rowing-201102130941070425/1190080772_RmZX2-Ti.jpg" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow {width: 100px; height: 66px; font-size: 0; overflow: hidden;}
```

Javascript:

```
var counter = 0;

function gotoNextSlide() {
    var $ss = $("#slideshow");
    if (counter >= $ss.children().length - 1) {
        counter = 0;
    } else {
        counter++;
    }
    $ss.animate({'scrollTop': (counter * 66) + 'px'}, 1000);

}

setInterval(gotoNextSlide, 3000);
```

Comment: thanks for your help and i'm sorry for My fault i want 2 seconds not minutes, and also I do not like a lot of talk, but I understand when there is an example So , please modify the code and the work of the necessary adjustments in order to become a code as I want to understand so well

Comment: Thank you so much for continue Help Me . I really want this same example, but using Javascript itself not jQuery or other

Comment: I have explained to you that doing good animation in plain javascript is a lot of work.  You can write your own function using a small timer interval to change scrollTop in small values if you want.  I'm not going to write that for you.  Using jQuery requires one script include in your page.

Comment: Ok but I've done it but with small problem .
http://jsfiddle.net/lionking/CyCDD/11/ The problem in the image top margin shows part of the previous picture. if you can fix or thank you for help

Comment: @Lion King "and also I do not like a lot of talk" - that's quite an attitude for participating in a site like this with the goal of learning something... If someone offers help on SO, in general the "talk" is the more important part of the answer!